# How to remove standalone attribute declaration in xml document?

Tags: java, xml, dom

Im am currently creating an xml using Java and then I transform it into a String. The xml declaration is as follows:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
doc.setXmlVersion("1.0");
```

For transforming the document into String, I include the following declaration:

```
TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING,"UTF-8");
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
```

And then I do the transformation:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
trans.transform(source, result);
String xmlString = sw.toString();
```

The problem is that in the XML Declaration attributes, the standalone attribute is included and I don't want that, but I want the version and encoding attributes to appear:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

Is there any property where that could be specified?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to get rid of `standalone="no"`? After all, the lack of `standalone` attribute is equivalent to `standalone="no"`: "If there are no external markup declarations, the standalone document declaration has no meaning. If there are external markup declarations but there is no standalone document declaration, the value "no" is assumed." http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-rmd

Comment: Because Im currently developing a system in which an electronic invoice should be generated. For generating the invoice, I need to create an xml which should follow the specifications done by the SAT (In Mexico). When an specification is not followed, the invoice becomes invalid.

Comment: Specifications that say an XML document must conform to such-and-such formatting convention, i.e. specifications beyond the content of the XML information model, require postprocessing. XML serializers in general are not able to fulfill arbitrary specs about serialization. (And I mean "arbitrary" more in the information science sense, not in the sense of "random.")

Answer (score 60, accepted):

From what I've read you can do this by calling the below method on `Document` before creating the `DOMSource`:

```
doc.setXmlStandalone(true); //before creating the DOMSource
```

If you set it `false` *you cannot control it to appear or not*. So `setXmlStandalone(true)` on `Document`. In transformer if you want an output use `OutputKeys` with whatever "yes" or "no" you need. If you `setXmlStandalone(false)` on `Document` your output will be always `standalone="no"` no matter what you set (if you set) in `Transformer`.

Read the [thread in this forum](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/6845084#Comment_6845084)

Comment: I still get standalone="no" in output with Sun Java 1.6.0_35 on Windows 7

Comment: you can also set property of transformer - OutputKeys.STANDALONE to true

Comment: @JanHruby It should be set as "yes"

Comment: @Pangea it works, but when i do it, it doesn't print a newline after the prolog anymore!

Comment: transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, ""); Causes to add new line after prolog

Comment: The Oracle forum thread link given by this answer is broken. I think it was replaced with the following https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/6845084#Comment_6845084

Comment: @cooltea tx. updated the link